# nestjs: not able to resolve DI of the service in another within same module

Tags: node.js, dependency-injection, nestjs

Have 2 service `BookingProcessPublisher` and `bookingProcessService` under same module. Trying to DI in one of the service. Below is the code
`booking-processor.module.ts`

```
  imports: [
    Core,
    forwardRef(() => ListingModule)
  ],
  providers: [BookingProcessService,Logger,BookingProcessPublisher, BookingProcessConsumer],
  exports:[]
})
export class BookingProcessModule {}
```

`bookingProcessor.publisher.ts`

```
@Injectable()
export class BookingProcessPublisher implements OnApplicationBootstrap {
  constructor(private readonly logger: Logger, private readonly util: Util) {}

  async onApplicationBootstrap(): Promise<void> {
    try {
      
      this.logger.log(`Booking Process Publisher started`);
    } catch (error) {
      this.logger.error(`Failed to start Booking Process Publisher :${error}`);
    }
  }

  publish(publishMessage: bookingProcessPublishData) {
    try {
      // some stuff
    } catch (error) {
      // console.log(err)
    }
  }
}
```

`bookingProcess.service.ts`

```
@Injectable()
export class BookingProcessService {
  bookingProcessPublisher: BookingProcessPublisher;
  constructor(
    private readonly logger: Logger,
    private readonly BookingProcessPublisher: BookingProcessPublisher,
  ) {
  }
  
  async bookingProcessConsumer(booking: IBookingObject) {
    try {
      this.bookingProcessPublisher.publish({bookingId: 123, status:'created'})
    } catch (err) {
      this.logger.log(`Error at bookingProcessConsumer err:${err}`);
      throw err
    }
  }
```

All of this belong to same module. When I try to inject `BookingProcessPublisher` in `BookingProcessService` nestjs fails to load the application

output is like

````
[7:55:20 PM] Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.``` Thats all. It doesnt proceed further.
````

Comment: 1) are your provider classes marked as `@Injectable()`? 2) what is that `@private`? Is that a typo? 3) There's no errors it just hangs? Nest will usually at least write errors to the log before `process.exit(1)` so you can have something to debug.

Comment: It is injectable, and there are no logs printed

Comment: Do you have `logger: false` set as an option in your `main.ts`?

Comment: changed to true

Comment: `true` isn't a proper value. Just remove the option entirely if you have it.

Answer (score 0):

Need to make sure that `BookingProcessPublisher` is injectable (`@Injectable()`) and it looks like you have a spelling error as well

```
private readonly BookingProcessPublisher: BookingProcessPublisher,
```

should be

```
private readonly bookingProcessPublisher: BookingProcessPublisher,
```

Comment: It is injectable. corrected the typo as well. Still no luck